# How to translate "Regularly" (meaning: at constant intervals)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word/adjectif/adverb that means that something is happening again and again after a fixed amount of time. I would be tempted to use "regule", but that word is unclear since it can mean "according to the rules".

Answer (score 10):

"regule" is good, "according to the rules" is "*laŭ*regule".

Answer (score 3):

I think that *perioda* is what you're looking for.

You could also use the Esperanto ability to create new words, for example - *regulrevena*, *regulalvena*, *denovfoja*. It depends on context which one is more suitable for you.